# Half-Angle Formula with Decimals

Tags: trigonometry

[1]How can I find $\sin (u/2)$ when $\tan u$ is equal to -2.642 in quadrant 2?

My steps for this problem:

- Create a triangle to find $\cos$
- label the opposite leg -2.642
- label the adjacent leg 1
- use Pythagoras theorem $1^2 + -2.642^2 = c^2$
- for $c$ I ended up with 2.8249
- Put $1/2.8249$ into the half angle formula

But after I put $1/2.849$ aka $cos$ I got the answer wrong

I know I am dealing with quadrant one for the half angle
so $cos$ would be positive.

I am not sure where my error was

My edited answer was .5683

Comment: Looks right to me, I tested it by just directly computing the angle and putting it into the sine function. What is the result you were expecting?

Comment: @orion a decimal to four places. My "full" answer was .56964... so I knew not to round up. I entered this answer and checked my values but my online homework software says I am Incorrect.

Comment: In that case it seems to be a rounding error. I get $0.568334$ to 6 places, so it looks your procedure with Pythagoras and half-angle, and then square root, lost some precision. You need more precision in intermediate results.

Comment: @orion So I found my error and placed the value into a variable to save the whole value. And for some reason I got the same answer as you and received an incorrect mark again.

Comment: These automatic checkers are sometimes picky about the number of places (do they want a specific number of digits - less? more? different rounding? extra spaces?). Sometimes it's even a programming mistake.

Comment: @orion I checked to see what the answer was and it was completely off what I got,  0.82279782607999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is easier way. Let $a=\cos u$ then
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}=-2.642$$
You can find that $a=-0.353993$. Now just apply the formula for semi-angle
$$\begin{align}\sin\frac u2&=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos u}2}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{1+0.353993}2}\\&=0.82279782607998754713733641975202928\end{align}$$
You'e got the wrong result because you performed a lot more computations and it yielded in precision loss.

Comment: That's exactly what the original poster already did. The problem is rounding.

Comment: @orion. He did more computations and it yielded in precision loss.

Comment: The correct answer for my problem was  0.82279782607999 @ThePirateBay

Comment: @JeremyHernandez. Yes, you're right. I calculated the wrong quadrant. Updated.